# UIButton that segues

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, segue

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

func transfer(controller: UIViewController) {
    let vc = ViewController() //View controller segueing to
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    let btn1 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 30))
    btn1.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    btn1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(transfer(controller: ViewController2())), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

The problem I am getting is this:
Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer
I am wondering what that means and how to fix it. I have tried replacing #selector with @objc and I have tried adding @objc before the #selector. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Error:** argument of `#selector` does not refer to an `@objc` method

Problem is not with adding the target on button. It is with the function `transfer`, It should be conform to `@objc` protocol because #selector can only refer to `@objc` method:

Keep the function like:

```
@objc func transfer() {
    let vc = ViewController() //View controller segueing to
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Add add the selector as:

```
    btn1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.transfer), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

Comment: and it can't have an arbitrary parameter like a view controller. IBAction selectors can only have the sender as a parameter.

Comment: @vacawama, I know that, but decided not to clutter my comment with that level of detail. I guess I could have worded my comment a tad more precisely: "An `@IBAction` method can't take arbitrary parameters. it either takes no parameters, a single parameter (the sender), or the sender and the UIEvent that triggered the action."